# Matching Files in SPSS using Table or In

Tags: merge, spss

I keep running into an error when trying to add variables of one spss file to another. File 1 has 1.800.000 cases [payments], File 2 has 800.000 cases [recipients]. They both have an ID number to match cases on.

For every payment in File 1 I want to add the recipient, from File 2. The recipients should thus be able to match for multiple payments.

This are the two codes I have been trying, which don't work:

#### code using IN

```
      DATASET ACTIVATE DataSet1. 
      SORT CASES BY recipientid(A).
      DATASET ACTIVATE DataSet2. 
      SORT CASES BY recipientid(A).

      Match Files /File=DataSet1
      /In=DataSet2
      /BY globalrecipientid.
      execute
```

When I use /In I don't get any errors, but the files don't properly match sin it doesn't add any variables.

#### code using TABLE

```
      DATASET ACTIVATE DataSet1. 
      SORT CASES BY recipientid(A).
      DATASET ACTIVATE DataSet2. 
      SORT CASES BY recipientid(A).

      Match Files /File=DataSet1
      /TABLE=DataSet2
      /BY globalrecipientid.
      execute
```

When I use /TABLE I get the following error:

*Warning # 5132
Undefined error #5132 - Cannot open text file 'S:\Progra~1\spss\IBM\SPSS\STATIS~1\20\lang\en\spss.err": No such file or directory*

I have run out of tricks, wouldn't dare try this in Ruby, and excel sadly is too small to handle this.. Any thoughts?

Comment: What happens if you use the build-in dialogue?
Sometimes that produces somewhat different code, which works...

Comment: It seems you have a problem with SPSS installation. SPSS can not open the error message to be shown in the output.

Answer (score 1):

Your first solution is wring because you are using `IN` subcommand wrongly. In other words you are matching Dataset1 with nothing.

> IN creates a new variable in the resulting file that indicates whether
>   a case came from the input file named on the preceding FILE
>   subcommand.

Your second solution. You are sorting dataset by variable `recipientid` but the `match files` is done by the variable `globalrecipientid`. Why do you sort by one variable but match by another? This could be a problem. And dataset names should be in quotes.

Solution 1:

```
DATASET ACTIVATE DataSet1. 
SORT CASES BY recipientid (A).

DATASET ACTIVATE DataSet2. 
SORT CASES BY recipientid (A).

Match Files
 /File = "DataSet1"
 /TABLE = "DataSet2" 
 /BY recipientid.

execute.
```

Solution 2. I never liked the implementation of datasets in SPSS. I did not trusted them. Other solution is to save datasets as files and do the match of files.

```
get "file1.sav".
SORT CASES BY recipientid (A).
save out "file1s.sav".

get "file2.sav".
SORT CASES BY recipientid (A).
save out "file2s.sav".

Match Files
 /File = "file1s.sav"
 /TABLE = "file2s.sav"
 /BY recipientid.

execute.
```

Answer (score 0):

My syntax looks somwhat different:

DATASET ACTIVATE DatenSet1.
MATCH FILES /FILE=*
  /FILE='DatenSet2'
  /RENAME VarsToRename
  /BY ID
  /DROP= Vars
EXECUTE.

Maybe this helps?

Comment: The code is shorter, but the result stays the same. No, it doesn't work. Thanks though.

Comment: I would guess that SPSS chokes on the amount of data - what Version do you use?

Comment: Can you try it with a small dataset with 100 cases each?
Than we will see if file size is the problem

Comment: @ChristianSauer, it seems to be the version 20 (from the warning message). I do not believe the size of files is a problem. The file sizes mentioned by OP should not be a problem for the SPSS.